# Combining results from two queries without common column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to be able write only one SQL statement that allows me to include the column called `qty_value` from the first query into the second query

These are the queries and the results of each one of them:

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    [Records].[Name], [Tables_Data].[Street_Number], [Tables_Data].[Qty_Value]
FROM  
    [Tables_Data], [Records]
WHERE 
    [Records].[Name] = 'John' AND
    [Tables_Data].[Street_Number] = '1510' AND
    [Records].[ID] = [Tables_Data].[Record_ID]
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    [Records].[Name], [Tables_Data].[Street_Number], [Tables_Data].[Description], [Tables_Data].[Account]
FROM 
    [Records], [Tables], [Tables_Data]
WHERE 
    [Records].[Name] = 'Tim' AND
    [Tables].[Name] = 'Owners' AND
    [Tables].[Record_ID] = [Records].[ID] AND
    [Tables_Data].[Title] LIKE '%Zone%' AND
    [Tables_Data].[Record_ID] = [Records].[ID] AND
    [Tables_Data].[Table_ID] = [Tables].[ID]
```

Results

```
Records.Name, Street_Number, Qty_Value
--------------------------------------
John, 1510, 6         
John, 1510, 3
John, 1510, 6

Records.Name,  Street_Number, Description, Account
--------------------------------------------------
Tim, 2121, St1, 4040
Tim, 5251, St2, 4141
Tim, 6578, St5, 4246
```

As you notice, there is no common column, therefore I was not able to use JOIN or UNION. If I use the WITH CLAUSE I got the cartesian product (9 records), which is not what I need.

I expect the following:

```
Records.Name,  Street_Number, Description, Account, Qty_Value
-------------------------------------------------------------
Tim, 2121, St1, 4040, 6
Tim, 5251, St2, 4141, 3
Tim, 6578, St5, 4246, 6
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: And what do you expect your result set to look like?

Comment: Given that the data from the two queries is completely unrelated, why do you want to get the results back from one query? Why not just execute both queries independently? It would be more efficient than any cobbled together way of joining the results

Comment: You could number your rows with a `row_number` function and join both queries afterwards. But, as above commenters say, the data seem to be unrelated.

Comment: @Nick because it will allow me to process it from the code more efficiently.

Comment: @Ярослав Машко I tried that, however, I can't use the row_number in the where clause.

Comment: Sure you can't use the `row_number` in a _where_ clause. You use it in a _select_ clause. As of my understanding, using such a function in a where clause, breaks SQL order of execution. See GordonLinoff's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `full join` and `row_number()`:

```
SELECT rt.*, rtt.*
FROM (SELECT r.[Name], t.[Street_Number], t.[Qty_Value],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.NAME) as seqnum
      FROM [Tables_Data] t JOIN
           [Records] r
           ON  r.[ID] = t.[Record_ID]
      WHERE r.[Name] = 'John' AND
            t.[Street_Number] = '1510' 
     ) rt FULL JOIN
     (SELECT r.[Name], td.[Street_Number], td.[Description], td.[Account],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.NAME) as seqnum
       FROM [Records] r JOIN
            [Tables] t
            ON r.[Record_ID] = r.[ID] JOIN
            [Tables_Data] td
            ON td.[Record_ID] = r.[ID] AND
               td.[Table_ID] = t.[ID]
       WHERE r.[Name] = 'Tim' AND
             t.[Name] = 'Owners' AND
             td.[Title] LIKE '%Zone%'
      ) rtt
      ON rt.seqnum = rtt.seqnum;
```

I also fixed the JOIN syntax and added table aliases.

Comment: I just tried your query. I am getting some errors as follows: 1) Incorrect syntax near 'ON' here : ```ON td.[Record_ID] = r.[ID] AND
               td.[Table_ID] = t.[ID]

Comment: Also, I changed the t.[Street_Number], t.[Description] and t.[Account] with td